# JSON - Sending string json to MVC Action Method - json containing a lot of data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have this:

```
function CallAjax(callback, action, method, data, dataType) {

$.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: method,
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});


}
```

My call to the action method using AJAX:

```
$(document).on("click", "#addprodcreate", function () {
    //pMetrics = pMetrics.trim("|-|");
    alert(JSON.stringify(arrayProductsMetrics));
    var json = JSON.stringify(arrayProductsMetrics);
    CallAjax(function (data) {

    }, "CreateProduct", "post", { jsonProduct: json}, "jsonp");
})
```

The MVC Controller with Action Method to call:

```
public JsonResult CreateProduct(string jsonProduct)
    {
        return Json(new { html = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The json contains an Javascript Array like this:

```
var data = {
    title: "Something",
    description: "Something",
    image1: "hf9847rhfr84ur4hoht4t" <- is a long byte array
}
```

I have:

```
var arrayProductsMetrics = new Array();
```

And there will be more than one var data stored in this array.

I put this in my web.config:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="150000" />


<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800" /> <!--50MB-->
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Tried this as i thought it was the limit of data being passed.

The error im getting is:

```
 Invalid JSON primitive: jsonProduct
```

The data may contain more images like image2, image3, upto 6 images but im only trying with one image.

Can someone tell me where im going wrong?

### UPDATE

I changed to this and now controller action method is being call but returning null.

```
function CallAjax(callback, action, method, data, dataType) {

$.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: method,
    data: data,
    contentType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});


}
```

And (jsonProduct didn't have single quotes):

```
$(document).on("click", "#addprodcreate", function () {



    //pMetrics = pMetrics.trim("|-|");
    alert(JSON.stringify(arrayProductsMetrics));
    var json = JSON.stringify(arrayProductsMetrics);
    CallAjax(function (data) {






    }, "CreateProduct", "post", { 'jsonProduct': json }, "jsonp");




})
```

It is now calling mvc but the string jsonProduct in my mvc method is coming back as null.

Comment: its because your post data is invalid. try without contenttype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ahmed Sunny was right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196897/json-sending-string-json-to-mvc-action-method-json-containing-a-lot-of-data#comment110003459_62196897):

```
function CallAjax(callback, action, method, data, dataType) {

$.ajax({
url: action,
type: method,
data: data,
success: function (data) {
    callback(data);
},
error: function (error) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
}
});


}
```

Removing the contentType worked.